# PHP no puede leer variable enviada desde un POST

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Estoy haciendo un `POST` desde angular a un fichero en `PHP` pero los datos que son enviados no están siendo reconocidos en el fichero `PHP`, ya he probado de varias formas pero sigo sin poder leer el parámetro `"op"` en archivo `PHP`.

El pedido es enviado al archivo PHP pero los datos que son enviados por POST no llegan. Si elimino la condición del if me retorna los datos de la querry. Pero necesito hacer la verificación con el IF y la variable 'op'.

**Angular controller:**

```
public getListStudents() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('contentType', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post("http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php", {op: 1}, 
    headers);
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-
    Type, Accept");

    require("conectar_mysql.php");

    if ((isset($_REQUEST['op'])) && ($_REQUEST['op'] == 1)) {
        $vec_res = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                array_push($vec_res, array('nome' => $row['nome'], 'idade' => 
                $row['idade'], 'morada' => $row['morada']));
            }
            echo json_encode($vec_res);
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

El problema ya quedo solucionado utilizando vuestra sugerencias $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) -> op; tenia que poner op para recuperar el valor. Lo que sigo sin entender porque es que no funciona el $_REQUEST o $_POST.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-
    Type, Accept");

    $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) -> op;

    require("conectar_mysql.php");

    if (isset($request) && ($request == 0)) {
        $vec_res = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                array_push($vec_res, array('nome' => $row['nome'], 'idade' => 
                $row['idade'], 'morada' => $row['morada']));
        }
        echo json_encode($vec_res);
    }
}

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Y si intentas con `$_POST[]` en ves de `$_REQUEST[]`

Comment: Lixus gracias por tu comentario ya habia probado antes de publicar la pregunta aqui con $_POST[] y sigue igual no le llega el dato

Comment: consulta, ¿como se llama tu archivo php?

Comment: se llama lo mismo que aparece en el post obtener_alunos.php

Comment: Bueno, preguntaba por que como dice 'alunos' pensé que podria haber sido 'alumnos'

Comment: Intenta esto `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); $request = json_decode($postdata);` y luego imprime tu variable `$request`, y si no me equivoco debe ser un arreglo o un objeto, yo me voy por lo segundo, y también prueba quitando los `header` de php, no los ocupas.

Comment: ahhaha es que esta en portugues no en español

Comment: no nada no funciona no llegan los datos

Comment: ¿Y qué dice nuestro amigo, el archivo `error_log`? ¿Si haces `echo $_REQUEST['op'];` obtienes algo? ¿`obtener_alunos.php` no estará en otra ruta diferente de esta `http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php`
?

Comment: esa es la ruta correcta porque si yo elimino del codigo el if me retonar la respuesta con la consulta de la base de datos pero yo necesito hacer esa comprobración enviando desde el post ese objeto hay es cuando ya no me llega nada en la respuesta ya que la condición del if no se cumple. lo del error log lo voy a probar

Comment: Buenas, probaste con agregar en el header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'? Saludos

Comment: Hola KN coloque en el controlador  let headers = new Headers(); 
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); y tambien en el PHP header('Content-Type: application/json'); pero mismo asi no funciona

Comment: Solamente dejaste el header con application/json? también probaría removiendo todos los headers del php y dejando solo un json_decode($file_get_contents("php://input")), y hacer solo un echo de eso.

Comment: Nada no funciona deje pero no muestra nada header('Content-type: application/json');

 echo json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); Voy a seguir investigando pero ya no se me ocurre lo qe pueda ser

Comment: ¿Revisaste el archivo `error_log`? ¿Qué dice `var_dump($_REQUEST['op']);`, colocado antes del `if...` ? Cuando te falle el código depura siempre tus variables, o sea, comprueba el valor que está recibiendo el PHP,  y revisa el log de errores para determinar el problema.

Comment: El problema ya quedo solucionado utilizando vuestra sugerencias $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) -> op; tenia que poner op para recuperar el valor. Lo que sigo sin entender porque es que no funciona el $_REQUEST o $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

Desde Angular, debes de preparar el envío del cuerpo de la petición en el formato que estás especificando, por defecto te lo envía como JSON.

```
public getListStudents() {
    const url = 'http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php';

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('op', 1);

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(url, body, { headers });
}
```

Desde el servidor PHP recoger en json como te indican en los comentarios y responder como lo estás haciendo.

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
...
die(json_encode($vec_res));
```